# multiple lists combines errors in R

Tags: r, list, dplyr, append, rbind

I have multiple lists wanted to combine, but got wrong results

The code I used

```
hiv.Scatter <- list(predictions = predictdata, labels = L)

for (k in 1:2){
  hiv.Scatter <-
    list(predictions = append(
      list(hiv.Scatter$predictions),
      list(predictdata)
    ),
    labels = append(list(hiv.Scatter$labels), list(L)))
}
```

But use the code above, I got very strange results

**the results I expected is:**

```
> str(hiv.Scatter)
List of 2
 $ predictions:List of 3
  ..$ : num [1:6] 0.0287 0.00648 0.00926 0.04352 0.01296 ...
  ..$ : num [1:6] 0.0287 0.00648 0.00926 0.04352 0.01296 ...
  ..$ : num [1:6] 0.0287 0.00648 0.00926 0.04352 0.01296 ...
 $ labels     :List of 3
  ..$ : num [1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..$ : num [1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..$ : num [1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The data I used

```
> dput(L)
c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
> dput(predictdata)
c(0.0287037037037037, 0.00648148148148148, 0.00925925925925926, 
0.0435185185185185, 0.012962962962963, 0.00833333333333333)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for answer, the result I posted is the expected output@Suren

Comment: You mean `hiv.Scatter <- list(predictions= rep(list(predictdata), 3), Labels = rep(list(L), 3))`?

Comment: Yes, but can you implement it within loop, in real data the L and predictdata is different for each loop, I need do it in a loop@Prem

Comment: Hey, did you see the two solutions?

Comment: a little mistake, "# $ L          :List of 3" should be " # $ labels          :List of 3"

Comment: True. Yout'd get the correct labels now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this,

```
hiv.Scatter <- list(predictions = list(predictions = predictdata),
                    labels = list(labels = L))    
for (k in 1:2){
  hiv.Scatter[[1]] <- append(hiv.Scatter[[1]], 
                                    list(predictions = predictdata))
  hiv.Scatter[[2]] <- append(hiv.Scatter[[2]], list(labels = L))
}
```

OR, this

```
hiv.Scatter <- list(predictions = list(predictions = predictdata),  
                    labels = list(labels = L))

for (k in 1:2){
  hiv.Scatter$predictions <- append(hiv.Scatter$predictions, 
                             list(predictions = predictdata))
  hiv.Scatter$labels <- append(hiv.Scatter$labels, list(labels = L))
}
```

Which seems to give the desired output

```
str(hiv.Scatter)
# List of 2
# $ predictions:List of 3
# ..$ predictions: num [1:6] 0.0287 0.00648 0.00926 0.04352 0.01296 ...
# ..$ predictions: num [1:6] 0.0287 0.00648 0.00926 0.04352 0.01296 ...
# ..$ predictions: num [1:6] 0.0287 0.00648 0.00926 0.04352 0.01296 ...
# $ labels          :List of 3
# ..$ labels: num [1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1
# ..$ labels: num [1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1
# ..$ labels: num [1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```